# C++: Segmentation Fault, malloc.c: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, malloc, segmentation-fault

I was solving a programming [problem](https://www.codechef.com/OCT09/problems/H1) in C++ which requires examining all the 9! permutation of the 3 X 3 matrix

```
1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9
```

I think, I have written the correct logic, and infact tested it on a 2 X 2 matrix(by tweaking the code for 2 X 2 from 3 X 3, ofcourse.), which results into the correct output being printed. But when I run the program for the actual constraint(ie. the 3 X 3 matirx), the program terminates with a Segmentation fault. Oddly when debuugged with GDB, it prints out

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff74f6bbc in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff7839b20 <main_arena>, 
    bytes=bytes@entry=12) at malloc.c:3353
3353    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
```

Here is the C++ code that I wrote:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int min_count;
map<string, bool> mp;
vector<vector<int>>vec(3, vector<int>(3, 0));

// n <= 17
bool isPrime(int n) {
    return n == 2 or n == 3 or n == 5 or n == 7 or n == 11 or n == 13 or n == 17;
}

// get a String representation of the matrix vec
string getStringRepresentation(vector<vector<int>> vec) {
    string str = "";
    for(auto i : vec) {
        for(auto j : i)
            str += ('0' + j);
    }
    return str;
}

void printRecursive(vector<vector<int>> &vec, map<string, bool> &mp, int count) {
    string str = getStringRepresentation(vec);
    if(str == "123456789" and count <= min_count)
        min_count = count;
    //cout << str << " " << count << endl;
    if(mp[str])
        return;
    mp[str] = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < vec[i].size(); ++j) {
            if(j != vec[i].size() - 1 and isPrime(vec[i][j] + vec[i][j+1])) {
                swap(vec[i][j], vec[i][j+1]);
                printRecursive(vec, mp, count + 1);
                swap(vec[i][j], vec[i][j+1]);
            }

            if(i != vec.size() - 1 and isPrime(vec[i][j] + vec[i+1][j])) {
                swap(vec[i][j], vec[i+1][j]);
                printRecursive(vec, mp, count + 1);
                swap(vec[i][j], vec[i+1][j]);
            }

        }
    }
}

// solve for each test case
void solve() {

    for(auto &i : vec)  {
        for(auto &j : i) {
            cin >> j;
        }
    }

    //cout << getStringRepresentation(vec) << endl;


    min_count = INT_MAX; 

    printRecursive(vec, mp, 0); // recursively examine all possible states.
    // if min_count is not changed(i.e. reamains equal to INT_MAX then the required state is unreachable, print -1 to indicate)
    cout << (min_count == INT_MAX ? -1 : min_count) << endl; 
}

int main() {
    int test; // test are the number of test cases, each will invoke the solve() function.
    cin >> test;

    while(test--)
        solve();
}
```

For a input

```
1

7 3 2 
4 1 5 
6 8 9
```

The program should have been outputting `6` but results in `SIGSEGV` as mentioned. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not use ` <bits/stdc++.h>` in code posted here. It is not standard. Try trimming the program down . The goal is a [MCVE].

Comment: Please do not post programs that need the would-be helper to enter values via `cin`.  Make the program self-contained.

Comment: Compile with all warnings turned on, and repair the code to remove them.

Comment: Fun puzzle. Would this program keep on swapping 7 and 4 in an infinite loop?

Comment: The question is fine, ignore the naysayers. But you should try to debug it yourself. E.g. do a stack trace in GDB when you see the segfault and so on

Answer (score -1):

Try using debugging print lines to see where the segmentation fault happens. Also, try to store the matrix as an array of 9 elements rather than a matrix.